# Platform Event Trigger Test: Set CreatedById OR catch trigger exceptions?

Tags: trigger, unit-test, platform-event, custom-exception

I have a Platform Event with a trigger I am writing tests for.  This trigger inserts a record and throws a custom exception if there is a DML error.  I want to make assertions about the message in that exception.

If I use `EventBus.publish()` and `Test.stopTest()`, the exception won't be thrown inside the test, since the trigger executes in a separate transaction.  So instead, I have my trigger logic in an Apex class, which I can test directly.

So far so good, but here's the wrinkle: my trigger logic sets the `OwnerId` of the record I'm creating based on the `CreatedById` in the Platform Event.  And Apex doesn't allow you to set `CreatedById` on the event record directly -- you have to actually create the record.  Which is fine if you're using a regular custom object -- you can query that type of info.  But Platform Events aren't queryable.

So now I'm getting a DML error, `INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: Owner ID: owner cannot be blank` -- but that isn't the DML error I'm trying to test for.

Is there anything I can do to set the `CreatedById` on the event?  Or alternatively, is there any way to catch exceptions that come from a Platform Event trigger execution?

Comment: I don't have an easy way to test at the moment, but System.runAs(someUser) should work for this purpose, I would think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fabricate a platform event using something like:

```
String theUserId = ...;

Map<String, Object> eventMap = new Map<String, Object> {
        'attributes' => new Map<String, Object> {
                'type' => 'MyEvent__e'
        },
        'MyField__c' => 'Xyz',
        'CreatedById' => theUserId
};

MyEvent__e fabricated = (MyEvent__e) JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(eventMap), MyEvent__e.class);
```

This deserialization approach allows you to fake out not just your custom fields but also the system fields as well, as shown above with the `CreatedById`. You can use this for platform events and ordinary SObjects too.

You can then pass this event into your apex trigger handler code as required.

Comment: It had occurred to me that I could always add a new custom field to the Platform Event instead of using `CreatedById`, but I like this solution better.  FYI, I excluded the `attributes` part from my `Map` and it still worked fine.

Comment: Nice. Yes, you only need that when the data is being deserialized without an explicitly set object type in the `JSON.deserialize`. I included it because it is a common part of the SObject in JSON format.